# Getting GoogleAnalytics working in all activities

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, singleton, google-analytics-api

I want to track all activities and button clicks throughout my 7 activities in my app.  Right now I am at the beginning of implementing GA.  I have it working in my opening main menu screen and can view it online on google.com/analytics.  My question is how to implement this into all activities?

Right now in my main menu class I have this:

```
private Tracker tracker;
private GoogleAnalytics ga;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainmenumain);


    EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this);

    //Get the GA singleton.
    ga = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);

    //ga.setDebug(true);

    //Use the GA singleton to get a Tracker object.
    tracker = ga.getTracker("UA-###-1");
```

Do I have to declare the 2 variables and then call `EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this);`, `ga = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);` and `tracker = ga.getTracker("UA-####-1");` in every activity?

I know there are similar topics out there but I am asking this for the new version 2 of `Google Analytics` and not the legacy version 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Analytcs V2, these are the only 2 lines you need in your Activities:

```
EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this); 
Tracker trackerV2 = EasyTracker.getTracker();
```

You are kind of mixing up V1 and V2 calls.  The tracker instantiation (associating your API key) is set via a attribute in the manifest, so you no longer need the lines:

```
tracker = ga.getTracker("UA-####-1");
```

Comment: Even though duplication code is needed for this answer, I am marking this as the answer since code was provided on how to implement.

Comment: Also, thank you for the clarification on how I was mixing up V1 and V2.

Comment: Google advises that the EasyTracker method calls should be in onStart & onStop. See https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/#tracking-methods.

Answer (score 2):

Implement a new BaseActivity to do the work in it's onCreate method, then make all your 7 activities extends BaseActivity.
Remember to call super.onCreate in your activities.

Comment: This approach is better as in your BaseActivity you can have all common functionality, reducing code duplication.

Comment: I hate using a BaseActivity for this sort of stuff. I think it obfusciates your logic into base classes that are largely untouched and evolve into giant customizations. However, that is a digression, and off this specific topic.  I also think for 2 lines, it is not worth creating a BaseActivity.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether 2 lines or just 1 line need to be add. It matters how many places you need to put the lines in. If the feature is really needed for all the activities, then use BaseActivity is a better choice.